# How to record a short audio clip as quickly as possible

Tags: voice-command, audio-recording

I'm trying to figure out a combination of apps/settings that will allow me to record a short audio clip (think reminder note) in as few taps as possible. At the moment I am using the standard voice recorder app. If I'm in the middle of listening to a podcast and want to record a short clip, I currently have to:

- hit the power button to wake up my phone
- hit unlock
- pause the podcast
- launch the voice recorder app
- hit "record"
- when I'm done, hit "save"
- resume the podcast

I'm looking for a workflow that will let me launch a recording app and start recording automatically (ideally right from the lock screen) then when I'm done save the clip without being told to and resume whatever was happening before (usually a podcast).

Can anyone suggest apps to look at, or settings that might help?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a job for [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), the most famous [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) tool. Other automation tools might be capable of the same (think about [llama](/questions/tagged/llama)) – but as a *Tasker* user I'll describe it this way (feel free to adapt).

The "task" to be exececuted would be:

1. **Keyguard › Off**
   Disable screen lock. Might require the *SecureSettings* Plugin if the native variant doesn't work.
2. **Media Control › Pause**
   to stop your podcast, music, or whatever media stuff might be running. This can be set as "toggle". You might need to experiment a little here; consider e.g. what would happen with "toggle" when no podcast is currently played – that would have the opposite effect then, so maybe better just "pause" here directly.
3. **Launch App**
   Select your voice recorder here.

Note that manipulating app controls is more tricky (and might require root). I didn't play with that, so I cannot give advice on it. I just know *theoretically* that *Tasker* is capable of that as well. Another tricky thing is the "continue podcast" part, which might not be wanted if it wasn't played before – but you've got the idea, I hope.

Now, we need a trigger and assign it the task from above. Multiple choices here with *Tasker* alone – and many more with the tons of plugins available (see e.g. my [collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker)). So I only give an example here which should make sense:

**Shake** lets you define a shake-pattern. So e.g. "shake the device twice from left-to-right" could trigger above action.

Even limited to the steps I've explicitly described, this would minimize the steps you need to take: Shake the device, hit "record", hit "save", and then (optionally) continue your podcast.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, I will go and check out tasker

Comment: Best start with our [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info). Tasker has a free 7-day trial available at their website to test it first, which you can prolong for another week by 1. exporting your config, 2. uninstall Tasker, 3. re-install Tasker, 4. import your settings (hint from the dev himself ;)